# Cyclic string replacements

Tags: java, string

Say I had the string "foo1bar2" and I wanted to replace to perform the following replacements in parallel with an expected output of "bar1foo2".

```
foo => bar
bar => foo
```

The string cannot be tokenized as the substrings might occur anywhere, any number of times.

A naive approach would to be to replace like this, however it would fail as the 2nd replacement would undo the first.

```
String output = input.replace("foo", "bar").replace("bar", "foo");
=> foo1foo2
```

or

```
String output = input.replace("bar", "foo").replace("foo", "bar");
=> bar1bar2
```

I'm not sure regex can help me here either? This isn't homework by the way, just geeky interest. I've tried googling this but unsure how to describe the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first replacing "foo" with something else that won't occur anywhere else in the String. Then replace "bar" with "foo" then replace the temporary replacement from step 1 with "bar".

Comment: I was kind of thinking of something similar but surely there must be a nicer way?

Comment: @Adam You could write your own method to walk down the String and search for the characters you want to replace. Basically this means parsing the String and treating each individual character as a token.

Comment: @Adam There might be a solution with regexes and capturing groups. I only have a vague idea where to start with that, though.

Answer (score 2):

I actually like Code-Guru's answer better, but since you said it's just a curiosity, here's a recursive solution.  The idea is to isolate just the piece of the string that you are replacing and recurse on the rest so we don't accidentally replace something that we already did.  Now if two of your rules have a common prefix, you may have to do some ordering of your rules to get the desired results, but here goes:

```
public class ParallelReplace
{
    public String replace(String s, Rule... rules)
    {
        return runRule(s, 0, rules);
    }

    private String runRule(String s, int curRule, Rule... rules)
    {
        if (curRule == rules.length)
        {
            return s;
        }
        else
        {
            Rule r = rules[curRule];
            int index = s.indexOf(r.lhs);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                return runRule(s.substring(0, index), curRule + 1, rules) + r.rhs
                        + runRule(s.substring(index + r.rhs.length()), curRule + 1, rules);
            }
            else
            {
                return runRule(s, curRule + 1, rules);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Rule
    {
        public String lhs;
        public String rhs;

        public Rule(String lhs, String rhs)
        {
            this.lhs = lhs;
            this.rhs = rhs;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "foo1bar2";
        ParallelReplace pr = new ParallelReplace();

        System.out.println(pr.replace(s, new Rule("foo", "bar"), new Rule("bar", "foo")));
    }
}
```